# What are the allowed characters for a password?

Tags: command-line, password

I'm asking for the type of characters supported by user passwords (the `passwd` command precisely)

Are spaces allowed? NULL characters (\0)? a subset of ASCII or more?

If spaces are allowed do I need to escape them?

Comment: Thats a general linux question, not really Ubuntu

Comment: @KasiyA As the shadow package is maintained by Debian (http://pkg-shadow.alioth.debian.org/) I preferred to get answers that could have been only applicable to its derivatives.

Comment: Ok @terdon and Syl ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on testing:

- `\0` is treated as marking the end of the password.
- Spaces are allowed. Though it isn't shown in the output below, by using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd>, I was able to use <kbd>Enter</kbd>, <kbd>Esc</kbd> and other keys in a password.

---

```
$ pwgen 10 1
Pohhei8sai 
$ passwd 
Changing password for muru.
(current) UNIX password: 
Enter new UNIX password: 
Retype new UNIX password: 
passwd: password updated successfully
$ printf 'Pohhei8sai\n\0\b\n\0\b' | passwd
Changing password for muru.
(current) UNIX password: Enter new UNIX password: Retype new UNIX password: No password supplied
Enter new UNIX password: Retype new UNIX password: passwd: Authentication token manipulation error
passwd: password unchanged
$ pwgen 10 1
Uuxohv9moo 
$ printf 'Pohhei8sai\nUuxohv\09moo\nUuxohv\09moo\n' | passwd
Changing password for muru.
(current) UNIX password: Enter new UNIX password: Retype new UNIX password: Bad: new password is too simple
Enter new UNIX password: Retype new UNIX password: passwd: Authentication token manipulation error
passwd: password unchanged
$ printf 'Pohhei8sai\nUuxohv9moo\nUuxohv9moo\n' | passwd
Changing password for muru.
(current) UNIX password: Enter new UNIX password: Retype new UNIX password: passwd: password updated successfully
$ printf 'Uuxohv9moo\ntesting 1\ntesting 1' | passwd
Changing password for muru.
(current) UNIX password: Enter new UNIX password: Retype new UNIX password: passwd: password updated successfully
```

---

From my reading of [the source](http://anonscm.debian.org/cgit/pkg-shadow/shadow.git/tree/src/passwd.c), the `passwd` command uses the (obsolete) [`getpass`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/utopic/en/man3/getpass.3.html) function, which behaves pretty much like `read -s` (and marks the end of the password string with `\0`). It does not restrict the characters usable, aside from some checking of reuse and complexity. `\0` cannot be used, since it gets treated as the normal end-of-string marker in C strings, but pretty much anything else can, such as the bell:

```
$ printf 'testing 1\nUuxohv\a9moo\nUuxohv\a9moo\n' | passwd
Changing password for muru.
(current) UNIX password: Enter new UNIX password: Retype new UNIX password: passwd: password updated successfully
```

Comment: This is a great answer, thanks for your tests and your time muru.